# Issue with bootstrap tooltips not closing on .checkbox-inline and .radio-inline labels with disabled checkbox/radio inside

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, google-chrome, twitter-bootstrap-3

Update: looks like mouseleave event doesn't fire on the label wrappers, and that is what the tooltip looks for.

My problem is best seen from the example here:

https://jsfiddle.net/bjvosa6h/

Basically I have some disabled checkbox/radio inputs wrapped in a label (.checkbox-inline/.radio-inline) and when I hover from right to left over the chexkboxes/radios, all the tooltips stay active.

```
<label class="checkbox-inline" title="Tooltip content..." data-toggle="tooltip">
  <input type="checkbox" value="1" disabled> 1
</label>
```

[image]

Not sure if this is a Bootstrap bug or something with event propagation in Chrome? Can't seem to get a good workaround. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This css rule will resolve the problem by allowing event propagation from the disabled input (Chrome prevents cursor events for disabled inputs) so the parent label element receives it.

```
.checkbox-inline > [disabled], .radio-inline > [disabled] {
    pointer-events: none;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

By default tooltips are attached to `hover focus`. If you set it to just `hover`, it should work as expected. Updated JSFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/bjvosa6h/14/

Comment: you're right; was actually just editing the jsfiddle; however, the Chrome issue still exists when the checkboxes/radios are disabled